# correct use of delimiter in sed regex

Tags: regex, sed

New to sed, so trying to figure out following problem.

```
sed -e "s/menuentry \"test.*(/menuentry \"test image ${VERSION} (/" \
    -e "s/menuentry \"Lost password change.*(/menuentry \"Lost password change ${VERSION} (/" \
    -e "sX/boot/[A-Za-z0-9\.\-\@_]*X/boot/${VERSION}Xg" \
    < test.txt
```

Above expression, the 3rd part

```
-e "sX/boot/[A-Za-z0-9\.\-\@_]*X/boot/${VERSION}Xg" gives an error
```

sed: -e expression #3, char 37: unknown option to `s'
if $VERSION=FIX i.e contains "X".

What is the better way to deal with this? use another character as a delimiter, i tried ":" and it worked.

Comment: Well, as you say, you can get around this using a different delimiter. There's your answer.

Comment: why'd you use double quotes?  If you're not going to reference some like a variable or a cmd (e.g. `$(CMD)` or `$VAR`) then you'd probably be better off using single quotes: `sed '/regex/'`.  That way you don't have ugly nested double quotes.  Don't use double quotes unless you _need_ them.

Comment: other delimiter right or escape the delimiter character in your variable (using a temporary variable or  `$( )` or a shell variable modification during the substitution

Answer (score 1):

awk to the rescue!

```
VERSION=FIX

awk -v VERSION="$VERSION" \
    '{
       sub (/menuentry "test.*\(/                , "menuentry \"test image " VERSION " ("          );
       sub (/menuentry "Lost password change.*\(/, "menuentry \"Lost password change " VERSION " (");
       gsub("/boot/[A-Za-z0-9.@_-]*"             , "/boot/" VERSION                                );
       print;
     }' \
    < foo.txt
```

Substituting variables into sed commands is Not A Good Idea™, precisely for the reasons you encountered. When you find yourself tempted to do that, consider using awk instead. It's less sexy, but it does not have this particular problem.